Tanstack query refetching even with stateTime/gcTime set to Infinity
I'm building a dictionary component, where data is fetched every time user changes a search term,  however, if he then changes it to a term that has been cached previously, I don't need it refetched, obviously data won't be changed. I have set both stateTime and gcTime to Infinity, but every time I come back to a previously fetched term, query refetches.
I couldn't find an explanation for this, so I can only assume cache is cleared when query key changes? Is there a way around it?
export const useSearchDictionaryQuery = (lang: Languages, searchTerm: string) =>
  useQuery({
    queryKey: ['searchDictionary', searchTerm, lang],
    queryFn: () => fetchSearchDictionary(lang, searchTerm),
    enabled: false,
    staleTime: Infinity,
    gcTime: Infinity, 
  });

Edit: the cache is not actually cleared, if I go back to a previous term, is shows the result immediately, but also starts a background refetch, which is what I don't need.

Have you tried removing enabled: false?

Yes, it doesn't change the behavior. Plus, I don't need to run query on the component mount, only for when input data is changed, that's why I set this option.

I understand. you could use getQueryData to try to get the cached data, but it's kind of avoiding the problem. Maybe lang is changing? or the component remounts?  adding some code would help.

i'm also guessing lang is changing. could it be that lang is an object and that the reference is changing eventhough the value is consistent?

Tanstack Query not to refetch the data when the cache is already available and the conditions (window focus, remount, reconnect) are met. Since staleTime and cacheTime are set to Infinity, the data will remain in the cache indefinitely, and no refetch will be triggered unless you explicitly call it.

keywords summary


refetchOnWindowFocus: false - Stops the query from refetching when the window is focused.




refetchOnMount: false - Ensures no refetch when the component remounts and uses cached data.




refetchOnReconnect: false - Prevents refetching when the user reconnects to the network.



export const useSearchDictionaryQuery = (lang: Languages, searchTerm: string) =>
  useQuery({
    queryKey: ['searchDictionary', searchTerm, lang],
    queryFn: () => fetchSearchDictionary(lang, searchTerm),
    enabled: false, // Manual control over when the query is fetched
    staleTime: Infinity, // Prevent staleness
    cacheTime: Infinity, // Keep the data indefinitely
    refetchOnWindowFocus: false, // Prevent refetch on window focus
    refetchOnMount: false, // Prevent refetch when the component remounts
    refetchOnReconnect: false, // Prevent refetch on network reconnect
  });


Try it. Let me know if you need further clarification!

